# Sailsjs Error: Cannot write to response more than once at onlyAllowOneResponse

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

Sails controller returns proper response for ajax request but when called via io.socket it doesn't work.

Socket Request:

```
io.socket.request({ method: 'get', url: '/example-service/', params: {}, headers:{}}, function(body, JWR){ console.log(JWR); })
```

Exception:

```
Error: Cannot write to response more than once\n    at onlyAllowOneResponse
node_modules/sails/lib/router/res.js:375:11
at MockServerResponse.send_shim [as send]
node_modules/sails/lib/router/res.js:192:7)
```

Socket response on the browser:

```
JWR {body: "Not implemented in core yet", headers: Object, statusCode: 501, error: "Not implemented in core yet"}
```

As per sailsjs documentation request / response will be automatically handled for websockets.

Am I missing something here. Do I need to send response in a different way for socket requests?

Answer (score 4):

Exception was because I was using res.render which was not supported in websockets by sails as mentioned in this documentation:

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/response-res

Fixed this by replacing

```
res.render
```

with

```
sails.hooks.views.render
```